# Why is 'srcset' attribute not working on the page?

Tags: html, css, frontend, srcset

I have been working on a project to develop a website. I want to use the 'srcset' attribute to apply different sizes of images on different devices. Here's how I define my image in the code:

```
<img 
      srcset="images/mobile/image-header-750w.jpg 750w,
              images/desktop/image-header-2880w.jpg 2880w"
      sizes="(max-width: 767px) 750w,
              2880w"
      src="images/desktop/image-header-2880w.jpg" 
      alt="" 
      class="header-banner">
```

But the browser is not detecting the mobile image which has 750px width.
[image]

Anyone knows why is this happening?

Comment: That screenshot looks like it was taken from a desktop browser, not a mobile browser. I see you have the Chrome Responsive Mode button enabled, but you need to show us that too.

Comment: This is a more of a comment than answer but I've been bamboozled by this in the past because the larger image was cached, and the browser is smart enough to reload the biggest cached version of the image. Be sure to check you've got cached disabled with inspector open, it could be working fine the whole time and you wouldn't know

Answer (score 0):

You must set "width descriptor" in `srcset` (aka `w`) and expected width in `sizes` (aka `px`, `em`, `rem`...).

```html
<img 
      srcset="images/mobile/image-header-750w.jpg 750w,
              images/desktop/image-header-2880w.jpg 2880w"
      sizes="(max-width: 767px) 750px, 2880px"
      src="images/desktop/image-header-2880w.jpg" 
      class="header-banner">
```

Remember that the browser still choose which image to use depending the expected size and the density (x1 for "classic" screens, and x2 or x3 for high density display, aka retina screen).

As example, by default Safari's responsive mode use x3 density. In this configuration, in mobile mode (approx 400px wide), it still shows the `2880w` image. The expected size is 750px in high density, it needs a 2250px wide image to render it at best condition. Safari will choose the closest image in the set (so `2880w` over the `750w`).